# Unable to convert string to numeric (int or float) when I'm reading from Serial Monitor

Tags: python-3.x

I'm writing serial monitor data from arduino to a csv file. But this error pops up every time:

```
"_line 27, in <module>
    fR = float (dataarray[2])
ValueError: could not convert string to float:_"
ValueError, it's not only for 'fR' variable but for other variables too and not at the same runtime.
```

This is how the Serial monitor output looks like:

```
1,31.00,,195.00,0.95,-21.53,67.58,70.90,21.61,-12886,32468,3748,-438,-753,340,233.00
2,39.00,0.00,209.00,1.02,-21.32,67.73,70.99,21.66,-12750,32468,3844,-579,-780,345,526.00
3,39.00,0.00,221.00,1.08,-21.28,67.79,71.33,21.85,-12722,32468,3796,-688,-775,411,138.00
4,39.00,0.00,231.00,1.13,-21.55,67.56,71.33,21.85,-12898,32468,3748,-455,-755,332,601.00
```

```py
import serial
import csv
Arduino = serial.Serial('COM5',9600)
Arduino.flush()
Arduino.reset_input_buffer()

while True:
    while (Arduino.inWaiting()==0):
        pass
    data = Arduino.readline()
    dataarray = data.decode().rstrip().split(',')
    Arduino.reset_input_buffer()
    iteration = int(dataarray[0])
    hum = float (dataarray[1])
    fR = float (dataarray[2])
    ppm = float (dataarray[3])
    Volt = float (dataarray[4])
    pitch = float (dataarray[5])
    roll = float (dataarray[6])
    Tf = float (dataarray[7])
    Tc = float (dataarray[8])
    AcX = float (dataarray[9])
    AcY = float (dataarray[10])
    AcZ = float (dataarray[11])
    GyX = float (dataarray[12])
    GyY = float (dataarray[13])
    GyZ = float (dataarray[14])
    Knock = float (dataarray[15])
    with open('DB_Store.csv', 'a') as outfile:
        outfileWrite = csv.writer(outfile)
        while True:
            outfileWrite.writerow([iteration,hum,fR,ppm,Volt,pitch,roll,Tf,Tc,AcX,AcY,AcZ,GyX,GyY,GyZ,Knock])
    outfile.close()
```

At every execution, the error changes without editing anything, although it still remains ValueError!! I don't understand how. This is a basic code to output the data to csv.

eg:

Run-1:

```
"fR = float (dataarray[2])
ValueError: could not convert string to float: "
```

+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

Run-2:

```
"iteration = int(dataarray[0])
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10:"
```

and so on....

Comment: These values on Serial monitor are as follows:
iteration, hum, fR, ppm, Volt, pitch, roll, Tf,Tc,AcX, AcY, AcZ, GyX, GyY, GyZ, Knock

Comment: What exactly are the values that it's choking on? Did you print them?

Comment: See basically I've connected 6 sensors and pulling the data from arduino from a port and I can see those values through Serial monitor. 
I need to append those values to a csv file in real time and then this file gets pulled onto LabVIEW (I tried direct LabVIEW-Arduino communication but didn't work, hence this approach).

Comment: @glibdud: Yes I can see those values clearly on a serial monitor, as well as when I'm trying to just print the whole line on a text file instead of CSV.
But I need the file in a CSV format and not in txt format.
Thanks.

Comment: Well, those errors indicate that you have data somewhere in there that can't be expressed as an int or float. If you know what those values are, you need to figure out how you want to handle them. We can't really make that decision for you.

Comment: @glibdud: Those values are actually int and float. About handling -> I just want to split the values wrt to ',' and read them and store them into appropriate variables.